# Eclipse ASTParser to parse only a java function?

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing

I just wanna know using org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser if it is possible to parse only a java function?

This is how I tried: I passed the code of a function to the ASTParser.setSource(char[] s) as follows:

```
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setSource(unit); //set source
    CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null /* IProgressMonitor */); // parse
    List list = node.types();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
       ASTNode typeNode = (ASTNode) list.get(i);
       System.out.println(ASTNode.nodeClassForType(typeNode.getNodeType()));
    }
```

But I see that the list of types contains nothing (size = 0).

Please suggest.
Thanks.
Fahim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small typo, in the line `List list = node.types();` it should be `List list = cu.types();`. You cannot pass a function only. It needs to be valid Java compilation unit, so it must have a type definition. Make sure you wrap your function with a class. Any class. It should work just fine.

If it doesn't work, remember that you can ask for `cu.getProblems()` and see where it failed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. This has been helpful.